using a formula with wilcox.test when paired = TRUE thrrows an error all of a sudden
I have a couple of code snippets, which, IIRC, used to work, but now throw an error.
To be sure I'm not making things up I googled boilerplate examples, and found a few, eg at STHDA:
before <-c(200.1, 190.9, 192.7, 213, 241.4, 196.9, 172.2, 185.5, 205.2, 193.7)
after <-c(392.9, 393.2, 345.1, 393, 434, 427.9, 422, 383.9, 392.3, 352.2)
my_data <- data.frame( 
                group = rep(c("before", "after"), each = 10),
                weight = c(before,  after)
                )

# this works as expected:
wilcox.test(before, after, paired = TRUE)

# this as well:
wilcox.test(weight ~ group, data = my_data)

# this, however, throws an error:
wilcox.test(weight ~ group, data = my_data, paired = TRUE)

The error message:
Error in wilcox.test.formula(weight ~ group, data = my_data, paired = TRUE) : 
  cannot use 'paired' in formula method

I'm using the latest R version (4.4.0) and tried it via the CLI.
Unfortunately, I can't try an older version at the moment, so I can't verify whether or not this actually worked, but since I found quite a lot of such tutorials I'm positive that I'm not just making things up.
So, any pointers what's the problem here?
Thanks!

Bug Fixes for R-4.4.0: "The formula methods for t.test() and wilcox.test() now catch when paired is passed, addressing PR#14359" See: https://bugs.r-project.org/show_bug.cgi?id=14359

@Edward Oh dear, this is embarrassing...if you turn this into an answer, I'll accept. Also, reading through the 4.4.0 documentation lead to me to find the proper example in the wilcox.test documentation: wilcox.test(Pair(before, after) ~ 1, data = my_data)

This issue is documented as a bug fix in R-4.0.0.
See https://bugs.r-project.org/show_bug.cgi?id=14359 for a discussion that has been running since August 2010!
Also, on the R News page:

The formula methods for t.test() and wilcox.test() now catch when paired is passed, addressing PR#14359; use Pair(x1, x2) ~ 1 for a paired test.


just as a caveat: wilcox.test(Pair(before, after) ~ 1, data = my_data)  disregards the data entry. It has to exist (otherwise it will error out), but it doesn't matter to what it points. In the above example, try rm(before); wilcox.test(Pair(before, after) ~ 1, data = my_data).

That's not true. R complains because the my_data data frame doesn't contain those two variables. Obviously if you remove before from the workspace, the command will fail.

define before, after and my_data as above, then df_dont_matter <- data.frame(NULL); wilcox.test(Pair(before, after) ~ 1, data = df_dont_matter). According to the documentation of Pair, both x and y are vectors (of equal length), that is there is no apparent (at least for me) way to define the split via the new interface.

I think they want you to do it this way: df_matters <- data.frame(before, after); rm(before, after); wilcox.test(Pair(before, after) ~ 1, data = df_matters)

On a Friday afternoon, that interface is...weird, gonna need to check out whether there are any pros compared to using a wrapper which allows formulae again. Anyway, thank you so much for your support!
