Bug in t.test {stats} function for paired/unpaired tests
The t.test function of stats package gives an error since the last update,  when data are in wide format, the t.test works, but when we put data in vertical format, then the t.test gives an error, as the example below:
x1 <- c(4.71, 6.66, 5.01, 4.6, 3.98)
x2 <- c(5.42, 7.1, 5.52, 6.05, 6.23)
t.test(x1, x2, paired=TRUE)
#> 
#>  Paired t-test
#> 
#> data:  x1 and x2
#> t = -3.1096, df = 4, p-value = 0.03589
#> alternative hypothesis: true mean difference is not equal to 0
#> 95 percent confidence interval:
#>  -2.029145 -0.114855
#> sample estimates:
#> mean difference 
#>          -1.072


data <- data.frame(
  group = rep(c("x1", "x2"), each = length(x1)),
  values = c(x1, x2)
)

t.test(values~group, data=data, paired=TRUE)
#> Error in t.test.formula(values ~ group, data = data, paired = TRUE): cannot use 'paired' in formula method

Created on 2024-06-18 with reprex v2.1.0
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.4.0 (2024-04-24)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20
Running under: macOS Sonoma 14.4.1
stats version 4.4.0

In the vertical format you should get the same results as in the wide format but instead I get the error

This issue has recently been documented as a bug fix in R-4.0.0.  "The formula methods for t.test() and wilcox.test() now catch when paired is passed, addressing PR#14359" See: https://bugs.r-project.org/show_bug.cgi?id=14359

thanks @Edward, but this means it has been documented or already fixed? I'm in R- 4.4.0 so it should be already working ?

The bug has been fixed in R-4.4.0. As the error message says, you cannot perform a paired t.test using the formula method. Previous versions allowed this and gave incorrect results if there were NA.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78458868/using-a-formula-with-wilcox-test-when-paired-true-thrrows-an-error-all-of-a-su/78459120#78459120
